# compiler says the extern variable is not defined

Tags: c, extern, iar

I get "Error[Pe020]: identifier "mVar" is undefined" by IAR compiler for the below code.

How should have I used the extern variable? I couldn't see what I am doing wrong.

//commonDefs.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
extern uint16_t mVar;
```

//file1.c

```
...
uint16_t mVar; //global declaration
...
static void food( void){
     mVar = 10;
}
```

//file2.c

```
uint16_t compVar;
...
static void mFoo( void ){
     if( compVar > mVar){
          ...
      }
}
```

Comment: Did you #include commonDefs.h?

Comment: It was not a comment, but an answer :) Please re-post it as an answer Sorry to ask such noob question.

Comment: everyone was a noob once, <Back in my day...> when some people were noobs they got to burn hours many trying to figure out noob stuff ... now it is so simple... I wish this site existed a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you #include <commonDefs.h> and it's also recommended that you initialize the variable in file1.c

Answer (score -2):

Declare mVar as `uint16_t` in the header and use extern when you are reffering to variable that is declared in another source file, that is use extern only in your source files. When you put `extern` in front of a variable the linker will look for definition elsewhere